# ¿Cómo poner un texto imborrable a un input y poder seguir escribiendo?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Quisiera que al intentar llenar un `input text` este se auto-complete con algún otro texto sin que se pueda borrar.

Tengo este código pero no me funciona, sí que me coloca el texto escrito en el primer campo al segundo campo, por allí todo bien, intente con darle un `value` al `email1` pero al rellenar la información en el primero el segundo borra toda la información.

Estos son los `input's` en el cual se escribe, el primero simplemente es para añadir los datos y el otro debería de mostrarme el autocompletado con los datos `@liber`.

> Nota: El siguiente *snippet* podría no reproducirse exactamente ya que contiene fragmentos *PHP*.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#email").keyup(function () {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $("#email1").val(value);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <?php if(isset($_GET['email1']))
   $_GET['email1'].='@liber';
  else $_GET['email1']='';
 ?>
<input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" name="email" id="email">
<input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" name="email1" id="email1" disabled>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomando tu propio codigo solo te falto hacer una concatenacion

```
$("#email").keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("#email1").val(value + '@dominio.com');
});
```

--- Respondiendo a la segunda pregunta que agregas en los comentarios

No, no es posible hacerlo en el mismo campo, dado que es editable por el usuario si llega a borrar un digito, cuando hagas una comprobacion y no encuentres el texto concatenaras de nuevo, por ende podria quedarte

texto@dominio.co@dominio.com

Dado que es un tema de UX mi recomendación es solo agregar el texto indicativo y hacer la concatenación en el servidor

```
<div class="input">
  <input type="text">
  <span>@dominio.com</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Aveces por unas simples letras uno se da mala vida, gracias funciono perfecto

Comment: Y como puedo hacer en caso de que solo quiera que se me mostrara todo en un mismo campo, es decir, que el @dominiio.com siempre este por delanto del texto y este no pueda ser borrado

Comment: @ernestojimenez, si te resolvió el problema, no olvides aceptar la respuesta y, si tienes otra duda, lo mejor es que hagas una nueva pregunta.

Comment: a ok gracias...